# Test whether list A is contained in list B

Tags: python, list, contains

I have two lists, `A` & `B`, and I would like to test whether `A` is contained in `B`. By "contained" I mean that the elements of `A` appear in the exact same order within `B` with no other elements between them. What I'm looking for is very similar to the behavior of `A in B` if they were strings.

Some elements of `A` will be repeated. We can assume `A` will be shorter than `B`.

There are many answers to similar questions on SO, but most answer a different question:

- Is `A` an element of `B`? (Not my question: `B` is a flat list, not a list of lists.)
- Are all the elements of `A` contained in `B`? (Not my question: I'm concerned about order as well.)
- Is `A` a sublist of `B`? (Not my question: I don't want to know whether the elements of `A` appear in the same order in `B`, I want to know if they appear *exactly* as they are somewhere in `B`.)

If the operation were implemented as the keyword `containedin`, it would behave like this.

```
>>> [2, 3, 4] containedin [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
True
>>> [2, 3, 4] containedin [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5]
False
>>> [2, 3, 4] containedin [5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
False
>>> [2, 2, 2] containedin [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
False
>>> [2, 2, 2] containedin [1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5]
False
>>> [2, 2, 2] containedin [1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]
True
```

Is there a concise way to perform this operation in Python? Am I missing some important terminology that would have led me to the answer more quickly?

Comment: will the first list always be of length 3

Comment: @TalhaIsrar No. Clarified the text.

Comment: are the elements in the list always unique?

Comment: @Cyzanfar No. Clarified the text again. :-)

Comment: i have left an easy ans hope it works

Comment: Um...someone want to explain their downvote? I put a lot of time into making it a clear question, and responding to requests for clarification.

Comment: but u have 4 upvotes?

Comment: Yeah, I'm not too worried. Just bugged me a bit since it was the second vote.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `any` with list slicing:

```
def contained_in(lst, sub):
    n = len(sub)
    return any(sub == lst[i:i+n] for i in range(len(lst)-n+1))
```

Or, use `join` to join both lists to strings and use `in` operator:

```
def contained_in(lst, sub):
    return ','.join(map(str, sub)) in ','.join(map(str, lst))
```

**Usage**:

```
>>> contained_in([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [2, 3, 4])
True
>>> contained_in([1, 2, 2, 4, 5], [2, 3, 4])
False
```

Comment: I have a love/hate relationship with that second suggestion. It's the hackiest, but in my opinion the clearest in terms of intent & syntax, and very concise. +1

Answer (score 3):

many people have posted their answers. but I want to post my efforts anyway ;)
this is my code:

```
def containedin(a,b):
    for j in range(len(b)-len(a)+1):
        if a==b[j:j+len(a)]:
            return True
    return False

print(containedin([2, 3, 4],[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]))
print(containedin([2, 3, 4],[1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 5]))
print(containedin([2, 3, 4],[5, 4, 3, 2, 1]))
print(containedin([2, 2, 2],[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]))
print(containedin([2, 2, 2],[1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3]))
```

this is the output:
True
False
False
False
True

Answer (score 2):

Assuming `a` always shorter than `b` what you can do is as follows.

```
 any(a == b[i:i+len(a)] for i in range(len(b)-len(a)+1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering you need to preserve order:

```
def contains(sub_array, array):
    for i in range(len(array)-len(sub_array)+1):
        for j in range(len(sub_array)):
            if array[i+j] != sub_array[j]:
                break
        else:
            return i, i+len(sub_array)
    return False
```

Comment: Nice. Even gives you the index of the first occurrence.

Answer (score 0):

Use this function

I tried to not make it complex

```
def contains(list1,list2):

    str1=""
    for i in list1:
        str1+=str(i)

    str2=""
    for j in list2:
        str2+=str(j)

    if str1 in str2:
        return True

    else:
        return False
```

Hope it works :)

Answer (score 0):

You can concatenate the 2 lists into two different strings. Then, write a function to check if one string is in another.

```
def containedin(a, b):
 if b in a:
  return True
 return False`
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
class myList(list):
    def in_other(self, other_list):
        for i in range(0, len(other_list)-len(self)):
            if other_list[i:i+len(self)] == self:
                return True
            else:
                continue

if __name__ == "__main__":

    x = myList([1, 2, 3])
    b = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

    print(x.in_other(b))
```

Answer (score 0):

No need to slice for every element:

```
def contains(seq, sub):
    sub_length = len(sub)
    sub_first = sub[0]
    return any(sub == seq[index:index+sub_length]
               for index, element in enumerate(seq)
               if element == sub_first)
```

Usage:

```
>>> seq = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
>>> sub = [2, 3, 4]

>>> contains(seq, sub)
True
```